# Too much memory used when dealing with BeautifulSoup4 in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I wrote a script which is fetching the HTML content of a page and analyze it.
Running this code in a loop, where I gave several URLs, I notice the memory usage was growing too much and too quickly.
Profiling and debugging the code with several tools, I notice the problem comes from the bit of code that is using BeautifulSoup4, at least I think.

```
Line    Mem usage    Increment     Line Contents                                                                                                                                        
59     40.5 MiB     40.5 MiB       @profile                           
60                                 def crawl(self):                                                                                     
70     40.6 MiB      0.0 MiB           self.add_url_to_crawl(self.base_url)
71                             
72    291.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           for url in self.page_queue:           
74    267.4 MiB      0.0 MiB               if url in self.crawled_urls:   
75                                             continue
76                                                                                                                                                                                         
77    267.4 MiB      0.0 MiB               page = Page(url=url, base_domain=self.base_url, log=self.log)
78                             
79    267.4 MiB      0.0 MiB               if page.parsed_url.netloc != page.base_domain.netloc:
80                                             continue                 
81                                                                                         
82    291.8 MiB     40.1 MiB               page.analyze()                                                                                                                                  
83                             
84    291.8 MiB      0.0 MiB               self.content_hashes[page.content_hash].add(page.url)   
94                                                                                         
95                                         # Add crawled page links into the queue                                                                                                         
96    291.8 MiB      0.0 MiB               for url in page.links:
97    291.8 MiB      0.0 MiB                   self.add_url_to_crawl(url)
98                                         
100    291.8 MiB      0.0 MiB               self.crawled_pages.append(page.getData())
101    291.8 MiB      0.0 MiB               self.crawled_urls.add(page.url)
102                                         
103    291.8 MiB      0.0 MiB               mem = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss
104    291.8 MiB      0.0 MiB               print('Memory usage is: {0} KB'.format(mem))
```

Here is what line 104 is printing each run:

```
Memory usage is: 69216 KB       
Memory usage is: 92092 KB       
Memory usage is: 105796 KB                                                                  
Memory usage is: 134704 KB                                                                  
Memory usage is: 158604 KB                                                                                                                                                                  
Memory usage is: 184068 KB                                                                  
Memory usage is: 225324 KB                                                                  
Memory usage is: 248708 KB                                                                  
Memory usage is: 273780 KB                                                                                                                                                                  
Memory usage is: 298768 KB
```

Using `tracemalloc` in the main file which is calling all the modules and running the `crawl` method above, I got the following list from `tracemalloc.snapshot()`:

```
/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bs4/element.py:744: size=23.3 MiB, count=210391, average=116 B
/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bs4/builder/__init__.py:215: size=17.3 MiB, count=335036, average=54 B
/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bs4/element.py:628: size=9028 KiB, count=132476, average=70 B
/usr/lib/python3.8/html/parser.py:327: size=7804 KiB, count=147140, average=54 B
/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bs4/element.py:121: size=6727 KiB, count=132476, average=52 B
/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bs4/element.py:117: size=6702 KiB, count=40848, average=168 B
/usr/lib/python3.8/html/parser.py:324: size=6285 KiB, count=85986, average=75 B
/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bs4/element.py:772: size=5754 KiB, count=105215, average=56 B
/usr/lib/python3.8/html/parser.py:314: size=5334 KiB, count=105196, average=52 B
/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py:587: size=4932 KiB, count=105197, average=48 B
```

Most of the files listed above are under the **/bs4/** folder. Now, from the moment the `page` variable (line 82) is not stored anywhere, `page.getData()` is returning a dictionary and `page.url` a string, why do I have BeautifulSoup getting so much space in memory?

In line 72 you can see how the memory usage changed from ~40MB to ~291MB (*considering the loop processed 10 URLs*), it's a big change considering that the data I'm actually saving are a small dictionary and a string.

Am I having a problem with the garbage collector or I wrote something wrong?

I'm not very practical with Python, so I hope the point I've made with the profiling and debugging is correct.

Comment: You can make a comparison by replacing bs4 with other libraries. For example, replace it with lxml or SimplifiedDoc.